# Identity server 4 application access

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to learn identity server 4 as a token server for a client application. I came across a very well written tutorial by Scott Brady. I am trying to start by using the sample code from the article at https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Example . The issue I am having is that when I login the “Client Application Access” screen give me a message “You have not given access to any applications”. Lots of searches and attempts have failed to solve this issue. I am hoping someone can point me in the direction of how to give access to applications. 
Thanks in advance for any direction.
Thanks

Comment: And what did you do that you get this error? Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

It's not an error message. The [View](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Example/blob/master/src/ScottBrady91.IdentityServer4.Example/Views/Grants/Index.cshtml) that your are seeing is because that you have not authorized any clients to access your profile.

After giving consent to client(s), The Page will show the list of clients that can request your profile data from the identity server.

I'm assuming that you're only running Identity Server. You need run both Client and Identity Server to understand the complete flow.